# Manually Creating Spline Piecewise-Polynomial

Tags: matlab, interpolation, numerical-methods, spline, polynomial-math

Consider a function y(x) sampled in an array of values, represented by the arrays `x` and `y`. If I have another x value `x0`, I can evaluate y(x0) using spline

```
y0 = spline(x,y,x0);
```

Now, I can also write

```
pp = spline(x,y);
y0 =  ppval(pp,x0);
```

**MY QUESTION:** If I already have the coefficient and x matrices, `my_coefs`  (`size(my_coefs) = [length(y),4]`) and `x`, how can I create a piecewise polynomial `My_pp` such that `pp.coefs = my_coefs` and that `y0 = ppval(My_pp,x0)`?

Comment: You are aware that a spline is not a polynomial? That it is only on the subintervals of the subdivision a (cubic) polynomial? -- So what you want is to evaluate the array of polynomials given in the rows of `my_coefs`? Why not just multiply the matrix with the vector `[1,x,x^2,x^3]`?

Comment: I know, and as I wrote, I'm using `ppval` rather then `polyval`. The nice thing about the `struct` that `spline` returns is that it is already a piecewise polynomial with its own array of points and polynomials.

Comment: So what you want to construct is a scalar valued spline. Essentially, you want to generate an empty spline object and fill its data fields with your arrays?

Comment: @LutzL That could be a solution, but I'm not sure that the "spline object" is any different from the piecewise polynomial object you create with `mkpp`

Comment: A (cubic) spline is a piecewise cubic polynomial where values, first and second derivatives are continuous. Thus indeed it makes sense that the data structure is created using `mkpp`.

Comment: @LutzL now the next question is - if both produces a piecewise polynomial, why is  `typeof(pp)=struct`? Why doesn't it have its own class?

Answer (score 1):

OK, There is no "spline object", but rather a piecewise polynomial object. So, if `my_coefs` was attained by break-points `my_x` then the code needed is

```
my_spline = mkpp(my_x,my_coefs);
y0 = ppval(my_spline, x0);
```

In case that dimensions are dazzeling here, which they are, then

`my_coefs` is 4*n

`my_x` is  n

`y0` is N

`x0` is N